# Print url only if doi not present

Tags: biblatex, doi, url

[this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/149324/22939) inspired me to make the printing of the `Url` and the `Eprint` field conditional, so that it only prints if there's no `Doi` field. Any pointers would be appreciated,

If I use the code posted below, I would like it to remove what I've striked out with red here,
[image: url and Eprint only if there's no doi]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=bibtex, style=authoryear-comp, natbib=true]{biblatex} %for digital version 
\bibliography{\jobname}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Holland1986,
    Author = {Paul W. Holland},
    Doi = {10.1080/01621459.1986.10478354},
    Eprint = {http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/pdf/10.1080/01621459.1986.10478354},
    Journal = {Journal of the American Statistical Association},
    Keywords = {Applied_Economics},
    Number = {396},
    Pages = {945-960},
    Title = {Statistics and Causal Inference},
    Url = {http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/01621459.1986.10478354},
    Volume = {81},
    Year = {1986}}
@article{Heckman1990,
    Author = {James Heckman},
    Issn = {00028282},
    Journal = {The American Economic Review},
    Keywords = {_MSc},
    Number = {2},
    Pages = {313-318},
    Publisher = {American Economic Association},
    Title = {Varieties of Selection Bias},
    Url = {http://www.jstor.org/stable/2006591},
    Volume = {80},
    Year = {1990}}  
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\citet{Holland1986} and \citet{Heckman1990} went for a swim. 
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: The inverse problem is over at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154864/35864

Comment: I don't think `Eprint = {http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/pdf/10.1080/01621459.1986.10478354},` is an `eprint` field. `eprint` is normally used for online repositories such as arXiv, JSTOR, Google Books where the URL can be shortened using some kind of unique identifier.

Comment: For example you may replace `Url = {http://www.jstor.org/stable/2006591},` with `eprint = {2006591}, eprinttype = {jstor},`

Comment: @moewe, thanks for linking that thread. I did see it, but I'm not really any good at writing functions in LaTeX/TeX. What do you use as the authoritative source in regard to what bibtex fields is meant for what? Like what is actually suppose to go in eprint and what about translators etc? Thanks.

Comment: The `biblatex` documentation has a short explanation about what each field does and what it means. The file `biblatex-examples.bib` contains good example usages of many fields.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To conditionally print the URL you could use the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=bibtex, style=authoryear-comp, natbib=true,url=false]{biblatex} %for digital version 
\bibliography{\jobname}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Holland1986,
    Author = {Paul W. Holland},
    Doi = {10.1080/01621459.1986.10478354},
    Journal = {Journal of the American Statistical Association},
    Keywords = {Applied_Economics},
    Number = {396},
    Pages = {945-960},
    Title = {Statistics and Causal Inference},
    Url = {http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/01621459.1986.10478354},
    Volume = {81},
    Year = {1986}}
@article{Heckman1990,
    Author = {James Heckman},
    Issn = {00028282},
    Journal = {The American Economic Review},
    Keywords = {_MSc},
    Number = {2},
    Pages = {313-318},
    Publisher = {American Economic Association},
    Title = {Varieties of Selection Bias},
    Url = {http://www.jstor.org/stable/2006591},
    Volume = {80},
    Year = {1990}}  
\end{filecontents}

% print url if no doi
\renewbibmacro*{doi+eprint+url}{%
    \printfield{doi}%
    \newunit\newblock%
    \iftoggle{bbx:eprint}{%
        \usebibmacro{eprint}%
    }{}%
    \newunit\newblock%
    \iffieldundef{doi}{%
        \usebibmacro{url+urldate}}%
        {}%
    }

\begin{document}

\citet{Holland1986} and \citet{Heckman1990} went for a swim. 
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You may want to protect a few line-ends there with `%` to avoid unwanted space. You could also add an answer using soucemaps similar to https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/154875/35864

Comment: @moewe Thanks for your suggestion about the %! I'll leave the the sourcemap for you, our biblatex expert!

Comment: +1: This is a great answer and I would love to see this as a package option :). (@moewe)

Answer (score 17):

Your MWE uses BibTeX, but if you are willing to switch to Biber (you really should look into it, Biber offers more features and BibTeX is officially considered a legacy backend now), you can use Biber's sourcemap feature.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear-comp]{biblatex} 

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map[overwrite]{
      \step[fieldsource=doi, final]
      \step[fieldset=url, null]
      \step[fieldset=eprint, null]
    }  
  }
}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Holland1986,
    Author = {Paul W. Holland},
    Doi = {10.1080/01621459.1986.10478354},
    Eprint = {http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/pdf/10.1080/01621459.1986.10478354},
    Journal = {Journal of the American Statistical Association},
    Keywords = {Applied_Economics},
    Number = {396},
    Pages = {945-960},
    Title = {Statistics and Causal Inference},
    Url = {http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/01621459.1986.10478354},
    Volume = {81},
    Year = {1986}}
@article{Heckman1990,
    Author = {James Heckman},
    Issn = {00028282},
    Journal = {The American Economic Review},
    Keywords = {_MSc},
    Number = {2},
    Pages = {313-318},
    Publisher = {American Economic Association},
    Title = {Varieties of Selection Bias},
    Url = {http://www.jstor.org/stable/2006591},
    Volume = {80},
    Year = {1990}}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\textcite{Holland1986} and \textcite{Heckman1990} went for a swim. 
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Heckman, James (1990). “Varieties of Selection Bias”. In: The American Economic Review 80.2, pp. 313–318. url: http://www.jstor.org/stable/2006591.//Holland, Paul W. (1986). “Statistics and Causal Inference”. In: Journal of the American Statistical Association 81.396, pp. 945–960. doi: 10.1080/01621459.1986.10478354.]

Comment: Thanks. Did not know BibTeX is considered a legacy backend. Could you recommend any sources on the BibTeX versus Biber question?

Comment: @EricFail See §3.15 *Using the fallback BibTeX backend* of the `biblatex` docs: "To utilise all of the features described here, `biblatex` must be used with the Biber program as a backend. Indeed, the documentation in general assumes this. However,
for a limited subset of use cases it is possible to use the long-established BibTeX program [...] as the supporting backend.
This works in much the same way as for Biber with the only proviso being that BibTeX is much more limited as a backend."

Comment: This works well for plain entries like articles. However, for an `inproceedings` entry with a crossref  to a `proceedings` entry this causes the bibliography to instead include the (even less desirable) URL of the `proceedings` entry. Is there an easy way to avoid this?

Comment: @bnord There is probably a way around that. But I expect the solution will be longer than is convenient to discuss in the comments, so I suggest you ask a new question (with an MWE for testing).

Comment: +1: Can this be applied to doi or arxiv? I can ask a separate question if that is preferable.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner The code already clears both URL and `eprint` fields if a DOI is present. (arXiv counts as `eprint`.) If that is not what you want and you can't find a way to extend this answer to do what you want, please ask a new question with an example and a detailed description of the desired result.

Answer (score 3):

This is not really a `tex` solution, but if you are using [Zotero](https://www.zotero.org/) with [Better BibTex](https://retorque.re/zotero-better-bibtex/) you can open `Preferences`>`Better BibTeX` and only export one

[image: When a reference has both a DOI and a URL, export]

Comment: although not answering the original question, this helped me a lot. Thanks!