# Biblatex bibliography style without URLs when DOI exists (in Overleaf with Zotero bibliography)

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, overleaf, zotero

I have a Zotero bibliography in Overleaf. I use `biblatex`.

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,citestyle=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{zoteroALH.bib}
```

Bibliography entries look like:

```
@book{de_saint-gervais_uniformization_2016,
    title = {Uniformization of {Riemann} {Surfaces}},
    isbn = {978-3-03719-145-3},
    url = {https://www.ems-ph.org/books/book.php?proj_nr=198&srch=series%7Chem},
    urldate = {2019-02-03},
    author = {de Saint-Gervais, Paul Henri},
    year = {2016},
    doi = {10.4171/145}
}
```

In the bibliography down the paper the reference shows like this: [image] 
There is the DOI, great, but also the URL which is unnecessary when the DOI is there.

How can I remove the URL when the DOI is present?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I really thought there would be a duplicate, but I could not find a good one. ([Biblatex: use doi only if there is no URL](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154864/35864) asks for the opposite and has a sourcemap solution. [Redundancy in bib file: conditionally suppress url if same as doi?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5660/35864) is asking for something slightly different and is not specific to `biblatex`, but has some `biblatex` answers, none of them uses a sourcemap, though. [Print url only if doi not present](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/424774/35864) is very close, the question additionally asks about `eprint`, but that could probably be ignored.)

My preferred solution would be to use a Biber sourcemap to completely remove the `url` and `urldate` field if the `doi` is present.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=doi,final]
      \step[fieldset=url,null]
      \step[fieldset=urldate,null]
    }  
  }
}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{de_saint-gervais_uniformization_2016,
  title   = {Uniformization of {Riemann} {Surfaces}},
  isbn    = {978-3-03719-145-3},
  url     = {https://www.ems-ph.org/books/book.php?proj_nr=198&srch=series%7Chem},
  urldate = {2019-02-03},
  author  = {de Saint-Gervais, Paul Henri},
  year    = {2016},
  doi     = {10.4171/145}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{de_saint-gervais_uniformization_2016}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Saint-Gervais, Paul Henri de (2016). Uniformization of Riemann Surfaces. isbn: 978-3-03719-145-3. doi: 10.4171/145.]